# How to make consul to use manually created PersistentVolumeClaim in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, consul

When installing consul using Helm, it expects the cluster to dynamic provison the PersistentVolume requested by consul-helm chart. It is the default behavior.

I have the PV and PVC created manually and need to use this PV to be used by consul-helm charts. Is it posisble to install consul using helm to use manually created PV in kubernetes.

Comment: For this to be directly supported the chart author would have to provide helm variables you could set. Check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @coderanger said

> For this to be directly supported the chart author would have to provide helm variables you could set. Check the docs.

As showed on [github](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/consul#configuration) docs there is no variables to change that.

---

If You have to change it, You would have to work with [consul-statefulset.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/consul/templates/consul-statefulset.yaml), this chart provide dynamically volumes for each statefulset pod created.

[volumeMounts](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/consul/templates/consul-statefulset.yaml#L100-L109)

[volumeClaimTemplates](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/consul/templates/consul-statefulset.yaml#L263-L278)

Use helm fetch to download consul files to your local directory

`helm fetch stable/consul --untar`

Then i found a [github answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729461/add-persistent-volume-in-kubernetes-statefulset) with good explain and example about using one PV & PVC in all replicas of Statefulset, so I think it could actually work in consul chart.

Comment: i felt the same and did checked code in consul-statefulset.yaml. that's why i am looking for alternate options like commandline options to helm rather than modifying the template directly.